# jquery adding class dynamically

Tags: jquery, css

i have a ul

```
<ul id="main-menu">
<li class=" mySelectedMenu"><a title="Dashboard" href="/">Dashboard</a> </li>
<li class=""><a title="Inventory" href="/inventories">Inventory</a></li>
<li class=""><a title="PJPS" href="/pjps/oldindex">PJPS</a></li>
<li class=""><a title="Reports" href="#">Reports</a></li>
<li class=""><a title="Today" href="#">Today</a></li>
<li class=""><a title="Discounts" href="/discounts">Discounts</a></li>
</ul>
```

dynamically i got title den i have to add class active in that `<li>` which title is same as that which i received. so how can i do??

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 3):

use `addClass()` to add a class... and attribute selector `[]` to select the element

```
$("a[title="+yourTitle+"]").parent().addClass('active');
```

[try it in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kG8vj/)

Comment: welcome.. glad it helped... :).. anyways if you thing this post helped you to get the answer then you can accept this as answer.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#main-menu li a[title=' + title + ']').parent().addClass('active')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dXch3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
var classname = $(this).attr('title');
$(this).closest('li').addClass(classname);
});
```

try this. Hope it will help u